# How can I group Javascript actions that force reflow?

Tags: javascript, performance, dom, browser, reflow

I have a project which is responsible for managing the rendering of elements, but I'm running into a performance issue replacing elements and then focusing on whatever had focus before.

Below is a minimal example that replicates the performance issue:

```js
const renderPage = () => {
  // get the old section element
  const oldSection = document.querySelector('section')

  // create a new section element (we'll replaceWith later)
  const newSection = document.createElement('section')
  
  // create the render button
  const newButton = document.createElement('button')
  newButton.innerHTML = 'Render Page'
  newButton.onclick = renderPage
  newSection.appendChild(newButton)
  
  // create a bunch of elements
  const dummyDivs = [...new Array(100000)].forEach(() => {
    const dummy = document.createElement('div')
    dummy.innerHTML = 'dummy'
    newSection.appendChild(dummy)
  })
  
  // replace the old page with the new one (causes forced reflow)
  oldSection.replaceWith(newSection)
  // reattach focus on the button (causes forced reflow)
  newButton.focus()
}

window.renderPage = renderPage
```

```html
<section>
  <button onclick="renderPage()">Render</button>
</section>
```

When running this locally, I see the following in the performance report in Chrome/Edge
[image: Performance Report, forced reflow is highlighted under both a replaceWith and focus event]

Both `replaceWith` and `focus` are triggering forced reflow. Is there a way to batch or group these actions so that only a single reflow occurs? I realize that there's no way to really get around this happening at all, but if I can batch them, I think that might improve my performance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, focus always causes a reflow: [What forces layout / reflow](https://gist.github.com/paulirish/5d52fb081b3570c81e3a)

So what you may do, is to reduce the reflowtime by inserting the new button standalone, initiate focus and after that you can append other childs:

Working example: [Example](https://codepen.io/coyer/pen/WNERvVO?editors=0010)

```
const renderPage = () => {
  // get the old section element
  const oldSection = document.querySelector('section')

  // create a new section element (we'll replaceWith later)
  const newSection = document.createElement('section')
  
  // create the render button
  const newButton = document.createElement('button')
  newButton.innerHTML = 'Render Page'
  newButton.onclick = renderPage
  newSection.appendChild(newButton)
  
  // create a bunch of elements
  const dummies = []; //  store in seperate array
  const dummyDivs = [...new Array(100000)].forEach(() => {
    const dummy = document.createElement('div')
    dummy.innerHTML = 'dummy';
    dummies.push(dummy)
  })
  //  insert new section only with new button
  oldSection.replaceWith(newSection)
  newButton.focus(); // always causes reflow; but fast because it's only one element
  //  store all other nodes after focus
  newSection.append(...dummies)
}

window.renderPage = renderPage
```

Comment: Thanks @coyer, this takes advantage of the fact that the render button is always at the top, which won't technically be true in my case, but there's no reason I can't split up the DOM into before the focusable thing, the focusable thing, and then after the focusable thing. It's potentially more logic than I would like, but that's something I can figure out.

Comment: Strangely, I noticed that compared to each other, both examples had around the same runtime. Did you notice a significant change when running yours? It no longer has the "Forced reflow is a likely performance bottleneck.", so clearly something is different (and in the absence of a better answer, worthy of being accepted), but I'm curious if this is just not triggering the warning because of some technicality.

Comment: I only measured the timing of appending and focussing the new nodes which was nearly twice as fast in my example and also checked that there is only the expected small reflow and the bigger one for complete reflow of childs.